# kubernates expose service with ingress on a certain port

Tags: kubernetes

Hi I have a react docker that uses nginx
with this service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    appcluster: ethernial
    app: clientweb
    visibility: external
  name: clientweb-service-ext
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: clientweb
  type: ClusterIp
```

I want to expose it, I have only 1 Node that is the Master, but the port 80 is already in use by apache running on master node (cannot shutdown it yet)
I want to expose my react app so I can reach it by http://:30000 for example
(I also need to expose other REST apis externally and internally, one hosted on a pod and each one uses port 80)

so how I setup my ingress?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: clientweb-ingress
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: clientweb
      port:
        number: 8080
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you have an ingress controller deployed? Ingress is just a resource type, and you need a certain ingress controller pod/service to apply the rules.

Comment: No I don't know nothing about ingress controller :(
for now I have only understood deployments and services

Comment: NodePort/LoadBalancer would be the way to go then! Do note: if you are using an ingress controller, it will have to use port 80.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the ingress controller using a NodePort service on port `30000`. Once you do that you can access backend pods exposed via ingress resource using `30000` port. If you are using nginx ingress controller then follow this [doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service) and the NodePort service(taken from the nginx installation docs) would look like below with your desired port `30000` and `30001`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.13.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.35.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
      nodePort: 30000 # Specified nodeport
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
      nodePort: 30001 # Specified nodeport
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

In this case you can still continue to have apache on port 80 on the host system.

```
curl http://NODEIP:30000/<path-in-ingress>
curl https://NODEIP:30001/<path-in-ingress>
```

Comment: what about the other pods that are asp.net core api (aspnet:3.1-buster-slim)?

Comment: You can run those pods in any port that you want and specify that as `targetPort` in a new clusterIP service and  new ingress resource having reference to that service.From outside the cluster you still use the same `30000` or `30001` but a different path as you would have mentioned in the new ingress resource. So same ingress controller is reused for all the ingress resource you create

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand the relationship between Ingress and Ingress Controller. Ingress is just a kind of resources, and it will do nothing except declare the ingress rules. All Ingress rules will need a certain Ingress Controller to implement its rules.

Then you need to deploy an Ingress Controller, typically a deployment(for certain pod) and a service(for external access). You can have a look at Nginx Ingress Controller at https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/ and use kubectl or helm to make the deployment. Do not forget to annotate the ingress-class as it will be used later.

After this, you can apply any Ingress to this certain Ingress Controller by adding `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation to your Ingress. And ingress controller(nginx server) will add your rules to its config, that means your Ingress rules has been applied.

Finally, as your ingress-controller-service has expose it self(LoadBalanceIp or NodePort from port 30000), all traffic to this endpoint will go through your Ingress rules and redirect to the desire service.